# Bootbox submit confirmation. Why onclick runs before submit even when it's ran with preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I've been trying to implement a confirmation box before submitting the form data.(Mind you, the default confirmation box is out of question due to lack of customization.)

As of right now I have this code using Bootbox.min.js:

https://codepen.io/IdontCommentMyCode/pen/XzEaMB

```js
function thatFunction() {
  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "CUIDADO! Ao proceder podera perder dados. <br> Pretende avançar?",
    size: "small",
    buttons: {
      confirm: {
        label: 'Sim',
        className: 'btn-success'
      },
      cancel: {
        label: 'Não',
        className: 'btn-danger'
      }
    },
    callback: function(result) {
      console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result); //Função default para demonstração do funcionamento


      $('from1').submit(function(e) {
        var currentForm = this; // Necessário 
        e.preventDefault(); // Previne o Submit do botão original
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
          if (result) { // Se callback === True então o  Form é submetido
            currentForm.submit();
          }
        });


      });
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<input class="btn btn-warning paddy" id="form1" onclick="thatFunction()" type="submit"></input>
```

What happens when I click the button is that the submission is made before the onclick function is ran. Which results in the forms being submitted and the confirmation only after it happens. From my understanding, the function runs, prevents out the default type="submit" and only after confirmation the form is submitted. Is my logic right at this current situation?

Aside from this issue, one of my questions was:

Is it possible, using a function, to turn a button into type="submit" and submit it at the end of the same function?

Comment: You have a typo where it says `$('from1')` and should be `$('#form1')`. Can you also console.log inside that submit function and make sure it's running?

Comment: Corrected the formating and inserted a console log into the function. It doesn't seem to work as there is no return log from inside the function.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. You have a onclick handler with a modal, and then inside the callback for that modal you add a onsubmit handler to the same button. What behavior is this code _supposed_ to have?